# boost::python::init<>() undefined reference

Tags: python, c++, boost, cmake

I'm trying to expose a simple class and constructor using boost python. I have the following:

files:

```
boost_test
    ├── boost_test.cpp
    └── CMakeLists.txt
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22.1)

project(boost_test)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED YES)

find_package(PythonLibs 3.8 REQUIRED)
find_package(Boost COMPONENTS python38 REQUIRED)

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} MODULE boost_test.cpp)

set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}")

set(CMAKE_SHARED_MODULE_PREFIX "")

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS})

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} Boost::python38)
```

boost_test.cpp:

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>

using namespace boost::python;

struct A {
};

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(boost_test) {
    class_<A>("A", init<>());
}
```

When I try to import the library in python I get the following:

```
>>> import boost_test
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: .../src/boost/boost_test/boost_test.so: undefined symbol: _ZN5boost6python15instance_holder8allocateEP7_objectmmm
```

If I replace the `init<>()` with `no_init` in the `boost_test.cpp` I don't get the error, but I won't be able to instantiate the class.

I'm really not sure how to fix this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is probably not related to your problem, but adding `-Wl,--no-undefined` into variable `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` is wrong. First, `-Wl` options are options for the **linker**, so it is simply not correct to add them via **compiler** flags. Second, all dynamically loadable libraries are built as `MODULE`, for which undefined references are not checked.

Comment: I'm fairly new to CMake, I just added the `-Wl` flag and after that I could see if the linking resulted in any errors. Before that it only gave an error when I imported it in python. How should I be doing this then? Can I not check for undefined references when linking?

Comment: "Can I not check for undefined references when linking?" - You build your library as `MODULE`, so undefined references are already NOT checked for it. No needs in additional linker flag.

Comment: Alright thanks. I will update the question to the python import having an undefined reference then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out boost was installed incorrectly. I'm not sure what I did wrong, but rebuilding the boost library fixed the issue.